# How do I know if I have received a POST request from a webhook to my PHP file?

Tags: php, json, http-post, webhooks

My file, request.php, makes a POST request to an API and immediately gets a response saying that the request is approved.

The POST request sends a callback url to which the API will send that JSON response. I am using receive.php as the callback url.

When I use a unique webhook.site/id as callback url I can see the JSON response. So I know that the API request works.

My problem is that receive.php is empty after every POST request. Why is there no JSON response to receive.php?

On my file receive.php I have the following code:

```
$body = file_get_contents('php://input');
$webhook = json_decode($body);
```

I have tried displaying the response with print_r, var_dump, echo etc.

The code on request.php:

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => 'https://api-url-with-my-key',
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>'{
    "pno": "number",
    "callbackUrl": "https://example.com/receive.php",
    "ipAddress": "8.8.8.8",
    "refID": "text123456"
    }',
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
?>
```

In chrome I can see the following warning "Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/json:"

EDIT:

The response from the API:

```
{

  "result": "completed",

  "orderRef": "98308bf7-c8be-4da6-8491-9f599d437de9",

  "pno": "number",

  "name": "a name",

  "checksum": "number",

  "certStartDate": "2021-01-28",

  "refID": ”text123456"

}
```

Comment: Your receive.php receives the data and puts it into a variable. That's all. It doesn't echo that data back, or do anything else with it. Also, we can't see what the other API server is actually sending to receive.php. All we can see is your request to them. To know why their request to you is empty, we'd need to see their request to you.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have updated my question with the response from the API.

Comment: So, that's the response to your cURL request to `https://api-url-with-my-key`, you mean? That's fine, but it's mostly irrelevant. If you're saying there's a problem with the webhook, then what needs to be investigated is what happens when the other API calls `https://example.com/receive.php`. That's a separate request, with a separate payload. Such a request will happen at some later time, and the PHP code in receive.php will process it.

Comment: Since that will be unattended, you probably need to make receive.php do something with the received data so you can see it afterwards, such as store it in a file or a database, or email it to yourself. echoing it won't be much use because it's only the remote API which would see that response.

Comment: Thank you for this response. I will try to send it to my email.

Comment: I have now added that I send one email if ($json = file_get_contents("php://input")) and one other else {}. But I just receive the email from Else {}.
Since I do get an email after my first POST request, I guess receive.php is triggered someway.

Comment: Log what `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` contained, to verify that your script was indeed requested via POST.

Comment: If you've put that code in receive.php then it seems like it's triggered, but yeah maybe doesn't contain what you wanted/expected. Why don't you email the actual contents of php://input to yourself then you can see exactly what's in it. And maybe email the output of `var_dump($_POST);` too in case the data is coming that way instead. And/or `var_dump($_REQUEST);`

Answer (score 0):

If you're saying there's a problem with the webhook, then what needs to be investigated is what happens when the other API calls `https://example.com/receive.php`. That's a separate request, with a separate payload. Such a request will happen at some later time, and the PHP code in `receive.php` will process it.

Since that will be unattended, you probably need to make `receive.php` do something with the received data so you can see it afterwards, such as store it in a file or a database, or email it to yourself. echoing it won't be much use because it's only the remote API which would see that response.

Answer (score 0):

I have now solved the problem. The web host have a firewall that I cannot manage or see, after adding the API IP-address everything works.

I did call them some week ago asking for this but they could help me then.

This code collects the response.

```
$body = file_get_contents('php://input');
$webhook = json_decode($body);
```